# Perl: how to produce a WSDL description of a package?

Tags: perl, soap, wsdl

I am going to write a *simple* SOAP web service in Perl.
It accepts two integers and one string in input and produces binary data (png file) to output (a QR code generator).
Can I produce it's WSDL description from the package source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never tried it but [Pod::WSDL](https://metacpan.org/module/Pod%3a%3aWSDL) looks useful.

Comment: Thanks. I did use it, with great success ;-)